# Facebook Integration with IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, integration

Hello guys I made Facebook integration with iOS with my app using Facebook Old API. I made all  the step by step procedure but whenever i run my application it will give me error on After Tap the Facebook button . Error is

"Sorry , the application you are using  is misconfigured for Facebook integration . please download the newest version of the application .

so guys please help me on this ...

Answer (score 1):

This is the newest version: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

The instructions for install are on the page. It's fairly simple to get set up. Just don't forget to put your facebook id in the plist! (Common error).

Comment: thanks dear but i used it but i have one problem that i just want that whenever i am taped Facebook button on my app screen then i want Facebook Login dialog box and User directly just post on the Facebook wall nothing else so like  old Facebook api so what changes i have to made . tell me the solution for this ..